# Excel =now() to change the hour not the day

Tags: excel, excel-2007, excel-formula, excel-2010

Good day. I am using excel and in one cell I have

```
=now()
```

When I do =now() -1 or + 1 it adds one day to my date. How do I do this method but instead of changing the days it changes the hour? Using =Time is not possible for me because I need the date as well. Is concatenation my only hope in being able to modify the hour within a date? Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As as commented by simoco use: `=now() + 1/24`